# How to handle windows pop up to upload a file in Linux machine using selenium script

Tags: linux, selenium, popupwindow

I am trying to automate a windows popup for file upload in selenium and want to trigger the script on LINUX.

There are tools like autoIT, JACOB which can handle these kinda pop-ups, but these doesn't work on LINUX directly.

I need help in any tool which does the job.

I have tried AutoIT, but due to autoIt exe not able to run the code on linux.
Then I tried JACOB but to use jacob needs to save two .dll files and did some exploration and found out taht Linux doen't support .dll it supports .so and as i am very new to linux don't have ides how to perform this.

```
 private void fileUploadData(String fileName) {
    String workingDir = "";
    AutoItX uploadWindow = new AutoItX();;
    try {

        workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        final String jacobdllarch = 
System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")
       .contains("32") ? "jacob-1.18-x86.dll" : "jacob-1.18-x64.dll";
        String jacobdllpath = workingDir + "/" + jacobdllarch;

        File filejacob = new File(jacobdllpath);
        System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH,
                           filejacob+System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();      
    }
    String filepath = workingDir + "\\src\\test\\resources\\testdata\\" + 
fileName ;
    File file=new File(filepath);
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    browseButton.click();
    uploadWindow.winActive( "File Upload", "" );

    uploadWindow.sleep(2000);
    uploadWindow.ControlSetText( "Open", "", "Edit1", filepath); 
    uploadWindow.controlClick( "", "", "&Open" );
}
```

Getting below error on LINUX code is working fine on Windows - 
Unsatisfied link error: no jacob-1.18-x64 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]

Comment: Have you checked if the upload node have a `<input> type='file'...` in html? Generally, you should be able to upload the file by using `sendkeys` to the file field element.

Comment: No the upload node is <input type='text'...>